# Add string to end of thread name

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multithreading

I'm printing out some data using logging module. Here is my code:

```
logging.basicConfig(
    format="%(asctime)s [%(threadName)s] [%(levelname)s]  %(message)s",
    level=logging.INFO,
    handlers=[
        logging.FileHandler("{0}/{1}.log".format(logPath, fileName)),
        logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
    ]
)
```

I would like to append some data to end of the thread name like this:

```
2018-10-30 19:43:54,304 [Thread-2 %SOME INFO%] [WARNING] Foo bar baz
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "log" methods of `Logger` class (debug, info, warning, ...) can take an `extra` argument who is a dictionary which can be used as custom attributes. The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.debug) says:

> The second keyword argument is `extra` which can be used to pass a
>   dictionary which is used to populate the __dict__ of the LogRecord
>   created for the logging event with user-defined attributes. These
>   custom attributes can then be used as you like. For example, they
>   could be incorporated into logged messages.

In your example, we have to add a new information in `format` attribute:

```
logging.basicConfig(
    format="%(asctime)s [%(threadName)s %(threadInfo)s] [%(levelname)s]  %(message)s",
    level=logging.INFO,
    handlers=[
        logging.FileHandler("{0}/{1}.log".format(logPath, fileName)),
        logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
    ]
)
```

And we can call a log method like this:

```
logging.info("Foo bar baz", extra={'threadInfo': 'SOME INFO'})
```